# Undefined command \rowcolors with xcolor package

Tags: tables, color

I am trying to make an alternate coloured table. However, I get the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.12 \rowcolors
               {2}{darkcerulean}{blue(ncs)}
```

My MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[tables]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\definecolor{coolblack}{rgb}{0.0, 0.18, 0.39}
\definecolor{darkcerulean}{rgb}{0.03, 0.27, 0.49}
\definecolor{blue(ncs)}{rgb}{0.0, 0.53, 0.74}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\rowcolors{2}{darkcerulean}{blue(ncs)}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\rowcolor{coolblack}
Table head & Table head\\
Some values & Some values\\
Some values & Some values\\
Some values & Some values\\
Some values & Some values\\
\end{tabular}
 \end{center}
 \end{document}
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: You have to load `xcolor` with the `table` and not with the `tables` option.

Comment: Silly mistake! Thank you @epR8GaYuh

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was due to a typo (`tables` option was used instead of `table`).